# Возможно ли выполнять вычисления на хостинге?

Tags: хостинг, планировщик-задач

К примеру, у меня есть аккаунт на хостинге, но я не хочу выкладывать туда сайт, я хочу, чтобы там например запускалась какая-то программа каждый час и что-то делала. Это возможно, или мне придется использовать веб-облако?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В панелях управления хостингом обычно есть планировщики задач, вы можете залить например какой-то скрипт на хостинг и установить в планировщике время его выполнения, период выполнения, количество выполнений в день, в неделю и т.д...

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Мой хостинг действительно имеет функцию шедулинга задач

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, шаред хостинг отличается от виртуального сервера только тем, что Вы ограниченны в выборе программного обеспечения и средствах удаленного управления. Хостер позаботился о Вас и предоставил Вам готовое типовое рабочее окружение. Вы теряете в гибкости сервиса, но выигрываете в удобстве и простоте управления.
Вам надо запускать системную программу, скрипт на php или может на bash? На хостинге может быть разный набор ПО, есть с поддержкой php, python, node.js и т.д., большинство поддерживает cron, с помощью которого Вы можете запускать свои скрипты, можно найти хостинг с поддержкой ssh, а на некоторых можно и свое программное обеспечение доустановить и пользоваться им в пределах выделенных ресурсов.
Но, как по мне, если Вам хватает ресурсов shared хостинга, то лучше взять самый дешевый VPS сервер, выйдет не намного дороже, зато ограничений меньше.
А облако можно использовать, если Вам надо запускать ваши программы иногда, а все остальное время держать сервер выключенным, чтобы оплачивать ресурсы по факту использования, для экономии. Ну и плюсом гибкость в добавлении системных ресурсов при необходимости.